# Devise Не редиректит после авторизации

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Я создал новую роль - Admin, с помощью Devise.

```
rails generate devise Admin
```

в роутах:

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { sessions: 'admin/sessions', registrations: 'admin/registrations' }
  devise_scope :admin do
    get '/admin', to: 'admin/admins#index'
  end
```

в контроллере: 
Admin/sessions_controller.rb
Admin/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Admin::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end

class Admin::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

В пути: localhost:3000/admin/sign_in -  У меня форма авторизации, когда я кликаю на кнопку'Login' он не куда не редиректи, не показывает не каких ошибок, просто находится на этой же странице localhost:3000/admin/sign_in

```
Started POST "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-19 20:41:12 +0600
Processing by Admins::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WyJosiI1ynmsdCai0Dve0Lg1bm2OpQ7usDsSDIS6M5mU8e0gMeoc3/McG32maYs/ro5hdhnJeyUP2bnr9MAE7w==", "admin"=>{"email"=>"raf@mail.ruh", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Admin Exists (27.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."email" = 'raf@mail.ruh' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered admins/shared/_links.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered admins/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 521ms (Views: 78.3ms | ActiveRecord: 27.8ms)
```

Не как не могу понять, почему?

Comment: Ну, приведённые выше фрагменты кода не имеют к этому решительно никакого отношения. Надо смотреть, какая получилась разметка и какие запросы совершаются.

Comment: я добавил логи, которые происходят в момент нажатия на "login"

Comment: (0.1ms)  BEGIN
    Admin Exists (27.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."email" = 'raf@mail.ruh' LIMIT 1
    (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK

намекает нам на ошибку при логине. не создается сессия.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

### Пара логин-пароль неверна.

[README напоминает](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers):

> Remember that Devise uses flash messages to let users know if sign in was successful or unsuccessful. Devise expects your application to call `flash[:notice]` and `flash[:alert]` as appropriate.

После запроса в `flash[:alert]` находится сообщение об ошибке входа.

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/SessionsController#create-instance_method) по обработчику сессий есть такая строка:

```
# ...
respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
# ...
```

Определив метод `after_sign_in_path_for` можно добиться результата. Вот пример, работающий у меня. Моя модель называется `Members`, `edit_member_registration_path` — путь на редактирование пользователя:

```
module Members
  # Custom controller for Members
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    # The path used after sign up.
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      edit_member_registration_path resource
    end
end
```